# Checking translation of "ubi vitam amavisti, illuc reverteris"

Tags: translation-check

I heard once someone say: "where you loved life, there you will return". My attempt to translate that into Latin is

> ubi vitam amavisti, illuc revertēris

Is that correct? Or is there a way to improve that?

Answer (score 6):

The translation is fine, but a few points:

- at first I thought *eō* would be more fitting as a relative reference to *ubi* than *illūc*, but judging by [PHI](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=) both are equally fine, with the latter having more demonstrative force:

> Num mē **illūc** dūcis, **ubi** lapis lapidem terit? (Pl.As.31)
>   Sed adhibeat ōrātiō modum et redeat **illūc**, **unde** dēflexit. (Cic.Tusc.5.80.1)
>   ..quae intrāre **eō ubi** jam virtūs honestumque est non potest.  (SenPhil.Dial.2.5.3.)
>   ..ipse **eō**dem **unde** redierat proficīscitur. (Caes.Gal.5.11.8.)

- *Istūc*, suggested by another answer, cannot be used thus because the place it points to is in the general vicinity of the conversation (probably but not necessarily near the addressee, either physically or textually, e.g. mentioned by them).
- The circumlocution *quō locī* [seems to be technical or colloquial](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23quo%20loci) and thus doesn't fit.
- Unsyncopated -ā(vi)s- forms are archaising in Classical Latin, to the point that for a word like *amāre* they [might not even be attested](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=amavis) (though one does for *adamāre*, in a philosophical work, in its elevated literary meaning). Quintilian, who lived in the 1st c. AD, lists mirror forms in -īvis- as examples of ["most obnoxious pedantry"](https://latin.packhum.org/loc/1002/1/7/5024-5036#7). I suggest avoiding these forms unless you're going for a consciously literary effect, and using *amāstī*, or indeed that same *adamāstī* of Cicero that will underline the start of genuine love for life.

Comment: The rarity of unsyncopated perfect forms was news to me. That's a very interesting point!

Answer (score 4):

It seems *mostly* fine to me. I would, however, propose the following changes:

- Utilize the adverb *quō* instead of *ubi* to eliminate potential temporal-spatial ambiguity.
- Utilize the adverb *istuc* instead of *illuc*. You are referring to place which pragmatically is close to the addressee but not to you, the speaker; the use of a 2nd person demonstrative is therefore justified.
- Optionally syncopate the form *amāvistī* into *amāstī*.

Thus:

> Quō vītam amā(vi)stī, istuc revertēris.

Comment: I agree with you that *ubi* with a perfect is somewhat ambiguous: I read it as "when" at first. But using *quo* as "where" would probably be rare as well; Lewis and Short say this: `'Where' (rare but class.): "respondit, se nescire, quo loci esset", Cic. Att. 8, 10: "quo loci illa nasceretur", id. Div. 2, 66, 135: "mitte sectari rosa quo locorum Sera moretur", Hor. C. 1, 38, 3.—`. Notice the addition of a genitive *loci/locorum* to clarify *quo*.
http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=quo&filter=CUTF8

Comment: @Cerberus Ah, thank you for that information! I was not aware of the rarity *quō* alone possessed. Would you recommend the addition of *locī* (or *locōrum*) here, or would it be sufficient alone?

Comment: Mm I'm not sure! L&S aren't exactly definitive.